# Plugin Freewall, cannot get wall function to work

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to create a grid style layout for my homepage that pulls random information every time the user loads the page. I have created the function but cannot even get it to display the wall items.

Here is the code I am using. Please point me in the right direction and I will be able to solve it but I cannot find my issue right now.

```
$(function() {

                        var temp = "<div class='bubble eventBrick' id='{brickID}' style='width:{width}px; height: {height}px;'><div class='rectangle' style='background: {ribbonColor};'><h2>{brickInfo}</h2></div><div class='triangle-l'><div class='info' style='border-color: transparent {triColor} transparent transparent;'></div> <!-- Left triangle --></div>";
                        var w = 1, h = 1, html = '', limitEventItem = 16, podcastBrick = 1, longBrick = 3;
                        var wallBricks = [
                            'podBrick',
                            'longBrick',
                            'trackBrick',
                            'newsBrick',
                            'socialBrick',
                            'photoBrick'
                        ]

                        var wallBrickList = new Array();
                        var total = limitEventItem;


                        var trackBrickLimit = 3;
                        var newsBrickLimit = 3;
                        var socialBrickLimit = 3;
                        var photoBrickLimit = 3;


            var eventWall = new freewall("#eventWall");
            eventWall.reset({
            selector: '.eventBrick',
            animate: true,
            cellW: 156.5,
            cellH: 136,
            delay: 15,
                            gutterX: 24,
                            gutterY: 10,
            onResize: function(){
                eventWall.fitZone();
            }
            });
                        for (t = 0; t <= trackBrickLimit; t++){
                            h = 1;
                            w = 1;
                            html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, h*100).replace(/\{width\}/g, w*100).replace("{brickInfo}", "Track Item").replace("{ribbonColor}", "#7f9db9").replace("{triColor}", "#7f9db9");
                            $("#eventWall").html(html);
                            html = '';
                        }

                        for (n = 0; n <= newsBrickLimit; n++) {
                            h = 1;
                            w = 1;
                            html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, h*100).replace(/\{width\}/g, w*100).replace("{brickInfo}", "News Item").replace("{ribbonColor}", "#FF9933").replace("{triColor}", "#FF9933");
                            $("#eventWall").html(html);
                            html = '';
                        }

                        for (s = 0; s <= socialBrickLimit; s++) {
                            h = 1;
                            w = 1;
                            html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, h*100).replace(/\{width\}/g, w*100).replace("{brickInfo}", "Social Item").replace("{ribbonColor}", "#3366FF").replace("{triColor}", "#3366FF");
                            $("#eventWall").html(html);
                            html = '';
                        }

                        for (p = 0; p <= photoBrickLimit; p++) {
                            h = 1;
                            w = 1;
                            html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, h*100).replace(/\{width\}/g, w*100).replace("{brickInfo}", "Photo Item").replace("{ribbonColor}", "#33FF00").replace("{triColor}", "#33FF00");
                            $("#eventWall").html(html);
                            html = '';
                        }
                    eventWall.fitZone((600), (815));

                    function randomList(total) {
                        var brickLimit = total;
                        var brickTotal = 0;

                        var news = Math.floor((Math.random()*4) +1);

                        brickTotal += news;

                        if (brickTotal <= 2) {
                            var social = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
                            var tracks = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);

                            brickTotal = brickTotal + social + tracks;

                            if (brickTotal <= 10) {
                                extraBanner = 1;
                                var photo = brickTotal - total - 1;
                            } else {
                                    var photo = brickTotal - total - 1;
                            }

                            } else {
                            var social = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
                            var photo = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);
                                var tracks = brickLimit - news - photo - social;
                            }

                        var brickCount = new Object()

                        brickCount[0] = track;
                        brickCount[1] = news;
                        brickCount[2] = social;
                            brickCount[3] = photo;

                        return brickCount;
                    }

        });
```

If I am missing a concept please tell me the concept, where I can learn more and examples so I might be able to rework this by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the selector:

```
<div class='bubble {eventBrick}Brick'
```

and

selector: '.eventBrick',

Comment: I changed the div to <div class='eventBrick' and still nothing

Comment: I updated the code that I got to work with creating 1 "brick" but it seems to just create one div element and then replace the same div element.

Comment: Dont worry about it. I am using a couple different languages and decided to use PHP to pull from the table to post on the main page. Thanks though!